# Most effective SVM implementation for large classes and datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, svm

What's the best SVM implementation of SVMs in MATLAB? Right now I'm looking at PEGASOS and SVM-Perf, which both claims to have good performance with large datasets and classes. But there are so many implementation out there, and I definitely missed some. Can I get some other recommendations?

My application is in bags of word object recognition that uses the histogram of the words in classification.

Comment: libsvm is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

[Liblinear Library](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) is the best choice ever (especially for large-scale problems). It has interfaces for MatLab/Octave, Python, Java, etc.

Comment: and you can introduce some non-linearity by computing for example [homogeneous kernel maps](http://www.vlfeat.org/mdoc/VL_HOMKERMAP.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two major choices: [LibLinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) and [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm), both from the same authors. Their performances are absolutely great!
Is case of large datasets, LibLinear is indeed faster but you can only use linear classification. As instead with LibSVM you can use any kernel you like (but it's slightly slower).